# How to keep the divs aligned in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap to layout my page.
On a particular screen width, the `div` becomes misaligned because the title of one of the `div` is very long which occupies another line.

If the `div` next to it also have a long title (so both of them occupies 2 lines), then the `div`s will be properly aligned.

How should I configure the `div`s so that regardless whether the title is very long or short, the `div`s will still be aligned, that is for this screen `width`, I should see two `div`s side by side, instead of seeing the 3rd div moved to the right and the 4th div moved on the next line?

**CODE**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    forloop {
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6" style="margin-bottom: 25px">
            <img>
            <h3>
        </div>
    }
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 options:

- #### you can `clear:left` at each 3 item.

```css
.row > div:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
  clear: left
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/300x300" />
      <h3>Very big text here to make 2 lines</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <img class="img-responsive"src="//placehold.it/300x300" />
      <h3>text here</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <img class="img-responsive"src="//placehold.it/300x300" />
      <h3>text here</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/300x300" />
      <h3>text here</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- #### you can use [`clearfix` bootstrap class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-clearfix) for `xs`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/300x300" />
      <h3>Very big text here to make 2 lines</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/300x300" />
      <h3>text here</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/300x300" />
      <h3>text here</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/300x300" />
      <h3>text here</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a fixed size (height) for the `<h3>`, if you know it's maximum two lines of text.

Something like

```
h3{display:block;line-height:16px;height:32px;}
```

But @dippas suggestion is probably better.